# dynamic query to column to row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following table:

[image]

and I want:

[image]

It is not about pivot table.
I want a select query to get the desired query.

I want to make view from the query result.

Please help me.

Comment: People are not going to help you if you don't show some effort. Write a proper question, include your code in the question and then explain what you have done so far.

Comment: have a look at the `GROUP BY` part of a `SELECT` statement. Overall, you seem to have invested almost no work in researching. That is bad.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: But I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: Try writing some code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for your problem is to use `PIVOT`

Try to look at this: [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: Can you please provide me it in Mysql

Comment: @abhinawbharat04 , link in above answer has a solution, you need to do some effort to read and study, i am not going to do your home work.

Comment: What if I want to do it without prepare?

Comment: Actually I want to make view from the query result.